# Copy property's values between 2 inherited classes

Tags: c#, .net

Assume that I have 2 classes: A & B

```
public class A
{
public string p1{get;set};
public string p2{get;set};
}

public class B : A
{
public string p3{get;set};
}
```

I have an object 'a' from class A, I want to create an object 'b' from class B which copy all property values from 'a'. Normally, I must do like following:

```
B b = new B();
b.p1 = a.p1;
b.p2 = a.p2;
```

With this solution, I must lose many codes if I must assign manually. Is there any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Use something like AutoMapper.

Comment: You could use a serialiser (e.g. JSON) to serialise A and deserialise to B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look into using something like http://automapper.codeplex.com/ that will automatically map properties from a source object into a destination object for you using predefined rules.

then its as simple as configuring once like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();
```

And creating your new object like this:

```
B b = Mapper.Map<B>(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can write your own hydrator, if you like to, using reflection, so it will compare object properties, names and types.
2. Or you can use automapper as mentioned in another answer.
3. The third solution is to internalize adaption in code. Since "B" knows about "A", do

   ```
     public class B : A
     {
         public string p3{get;set};
         public void Hydrate{A a}
         {
             this.p1 = a.p1;
             this.p2 = a.p2;
          }
      }
   ```

   Then your code will be like this

   ```
      B b = new B();
      b.Hydrate(a);
   ```